# How can I print a two-dimensional array of characters in Java, to create a 20x20 grid?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print a 2d array of periods in Java, however, I can not get the formatting correctly. I am able to create a similar layout NOT using a 2d array. However, I will need to be working with a 2d array to finish the project. I have tried using `Arrays.deepToString();` but did not find it useful.

My goal is to have a 20x20 grid of periods like this:
** Without the S and the X
[image]

My way without using a 2d array:

```
for (int i = 20; i >= 1; i--) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                    System.out.print(" .");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
```

My try using a 2d array:

```
final int rows = 20;
final int columns = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
              board[i][j] = ".";
     }
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board));
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, pls can you elaborate more like what do you need in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print your 2D array outside `outer loop` but you print this 2D array result outside `inner loop`. After that you have to remove `bracket` and `comma` through java [**replace()**](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_replace.asp) method.

Here down is modified code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int rows = 20;
        final int columns = 20;
        String board[][] = new String[rows][columns];
        
        // OUTER LOOP
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            // INNER LOOP
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                board[i][j] = ".";
            }
        }
        System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(board).replace("],", "\n")
                                                .replace(",", "")
                                                .replace("[[", " ")
                                                .replace("[", "")
                                                .replace("]]", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is great. It's really helped me lot

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: @RaymondNoodle Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

Put the two together?...

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {       
    final int rows = 20;
    final int columns = 20;
    String board[][] = new String[rows][columns];

    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
        board[row][col] = ".";
      }
    }

    display2Darray(board);
  }

  public static void display2Darray(String[][] arr) {
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(arr[row][col]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```